# New hanging format for all paragraph in a newly defined environment

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to define a new environment where all paragraph should adopt a new indention. I tried to use `\hangafter` and `\hangindent` to do this. However， these commands only apply to the first para after it. As is shown in the example below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %make first para after title indented
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newenvironment{poemcontent}{\hangafter=1 \setlength{\hangindent}{4em}}{\par}
\newcommand{\text}{This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. 
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content 
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a 
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Poem}
\begin{poemcontent}
  \text

  \text

  \text
\end{poemcontent}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution with  the  `everypar` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %make first para after title indented
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newenvironment{poemcontent}{\everypar{\hangafter=1 \setlength{\hangindent}{4em}}}{\par}
\newcommand{\text}{This is some content to be written as a single paragraph.
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Poem}
\begin{poemcontent}
  \text

  \text

  \text
\end{poemcontent}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Propagating the paragraph shape is exactly what latex list environments are designed to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{indentfirst,enumitem} %make first para after title indented
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\newlist{plist}{description}{1}

\newenvironment{poemcontent}{%
\plist}{%
\endplist}
\newcommand{\text}{\item This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. 
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content 
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a 
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Poem}
\begin{poemcontent}
  \text

  \text

  \text
\end{poemcontent}
\end{document}
```

As you see I just took the default values here, which may be OK, or fiddle with the `enumitem` options to customise it further.

Or maybe you would prefer this form which only uses a single hidden `\item[]` and just uses the blank line `\par` to trigger a hanging indent:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{indentfirst,enumitem} %make first para after title indented
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\newlist{plist}{description}{1}

\newenvironment{poemcontent}{%
\plist[listparindent=-2em]\item\relax}{%
\endplist}
\newcommand{\text}{This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. 
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content 
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a 
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Poem}
\begin{poemcontent}
  \text

  \text

  \text
\end{poemcontent}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are really typesetting poems, I strongly suggest looking at some of the packages which already support this. (Why reinvent the wheel?)

For example, [verse](http://ctan.org/pkg/verse) allows you to do something like this and is very configurable:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %make first para after title indented
\usepackage{verse}
\setlength\vindent{4em}
\newcommand{\text}{This is some content to be written as a single paragraph.
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Poem}
\begin{verse}[\textwidth]
  \text\\
  \text\\
  \text\\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: poem]

If you are typesetting a collection of poems, see [poetrytex](http://ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex) which is designed for this (and can be used with **verse**, I think).

Or, perhaps, [hang](http://ctan.org/pkg/hang) is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of variety, there's also the `hanging` package (which is a part of the `memoir` class). The following command will hang one paragraph:

```
\hangpara{ indent }{ afternum }
```

The following environment will hang multiple paragraphs:

```
\begin{hangparas}{ indent }{ afternum }
<text>
\end{hangparas}
```

Note: `indent` must be a length (e.g., `2em`), and a positive value will hang the lefthand side of the paragraph, while a negative value will change the right.

The `afternum` may also be positive or negative. If positive, then it affects the lines *after* the number (e.g., a value of `2` would mean the indent starts on the third line); if negative (e.g., `-2`), then the first 2 lines would be indented.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging,lipsum}
\parskip10pt
\begin{document}

\hangpara{3em}{-2}%
\lipsum*[1]

\hangpara{-3em}{2}%
\lipsum*[1]

\begin{hangparas}{25pt}{4}
\lipsum
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`xgalley`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xgalley)'s "multi-paragraph `\parshape` setting":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgalley}

% http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2015/0302-Joseph-Wright/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetAllShape   \galley_parshape_set_multi:nnnN  % Normal, left, right, resume
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetOneShape   \galley_parshape_set_single:nnnN % Normal, left, right, resume
\cs_new_eq:NN \True          \c_true_bool
\cs_new_eq:NN \False         \c_false_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment{poemcontent}[1][4em]
  {\par\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove regular paragraph indentation
   \SetAllShape{1}{#1}{0pt}{\False}}
  {\par}

\newcommand{\text}{This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. 
This is some content to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content 
to be written as a single paragraph. This is some content to be written as a 
single paragraph.}

\begin{document}

\text

\begin{poemcontent}
  \text

  \text
\end{poemcontent}

\text

\begin{poemcontent}[3em]
  \text
\end{poemcontent}

\text

\end{document}
```

`\SetAllShape{<normal>}{<left>}{<right>}{<resume>}` sets all paragraphs within the defined scope to have the first `<normal>` lines unaffected/normal, followed by a paragraph shape that is indented left/right by lengths `<left>`/`<right>`. This can be a comma-separated list of lengths. `<resume>` is either `\True` or `\False` depending on whether you want the indentations to stop or continue.